# Multiple calendars in one ics file

Tags: icalendar

I have a website that has resource data that can be exported as calendars ( .ics files).  It is an internal website and so the users will likely be loading them into Outlook 2013 so that they can cross reference the resource data with their own calendars.

I have run into the challenge that users can easily export multiple sets of data in one go resulting in multiple calendars being available to be download (the common worst case being 12 calendars, but there are going to be a few users who will push it well beyond that).  I can easily zip the ics files up and provide the zip as a single download, but my goal is to keep it at simple to use as possible for the user to import into Outlook.  From the research I have done and my own tests I have not found any way for .ics to have multiple calendars in one file.  As such here is my chain of questions:

- Does icalendar have a way of storing multiple calendars in a single file?
- If not is there a different calendar file format that Outlook 2013 can import and parse that does support multiple calendars?
- If there is no better calendar file type for this, is there a general best practice for providing multiple calendar files for download and import?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you say "calendar", but, to expand on [@jgm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38736844/73603), the specification allows more than one `VCALENDAR` component to exist inside of the same file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
...
END:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
...
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: When I do that Outlook does read both VCALENDAR elements, but it still treats them as a single calendar in Outlook even if I give the two VALCENDAR different names.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Agreed: while the [iCalendar RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.4) allow for multiple calendar entries, clients don’t always support that. In our case we’ve decided to send a single ICS file per event…

Answer (score 1):

According to [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.4) you can have multiple calendars in a single iCalendar entry:

```
The Calendaring and Scheduling Core Object is a collection of
calendaring and scheduling information.  Typically, this information
will consist of an iCalendar stream with a single iCalendar object.
However, multiple iCalendar objects can be sequentially grouped
together in an iCalendar stream.
```

However, you would have to test each client individually to see if it was supported as this is not a common situation.

Answer (score 0):

No. The iCalendar format has no notion of calendar "containers". The closest would be to use the CATEGORY property to distinguish between different types of events.

If you really only care about Outlook, the alternative would be to create PST files, which can contain arbitrary hierarchies. But generating those is much more involved in terms of development.

Comment: There's no notion of containers, but it's possible to have multiple calendar objects in the same file: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.4